# MariaDB access denied when connecting from PHP

Tags: php, mariadb

I have MariaDB installed on my server listening on 0.0.0.0:3306 and configured to accept connections from mysql.mydomain.com. It also uses SSL certificate generated by Let's Encrypt.
There is user named `test` with password set to `123`.
I can successfully connect to it using mariadb utility from my pc (Not Server) using following command:

```
mariadb -u test -h mysql.mydomain.com -P 3306 --password=123
```

But when I try to connect to it with PHP (running on the same pc as my command above) I get access denied error:

> PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught mysqli_sql_exception: Access denied for user 'test'@'(My Ip Address)' (using password: YES)

PHP Code:

```
$host = "mysql.mydomain.com";
$username = "test";
$password = "123";
$database = "test";
$port = 3306;
                
$mysqli = @new mysqli($host, $username, $password, $database);
if ($mysqli->connect_error) {
    die("Connection failed: " . $mysqli->connect_error);
}
```

I also tried disabling password for "test" account. And again I was able to login with `mariadb` command, but couldn't with PHP.
PHP-FPM has mysqli extension enabled.

EDIT:
Okay, so after changing mariadb logging config I got to those two log messages:

```
230826 18:10:24    900 Connect  test@My_Ip_Address on  using SSL/TLS
230826 18:11:38    908 Connect  test@My_Ip_Address on test using TCP/IP
                   908 Connect  Access denied for user 'test'@'My_Ip_Address' (using password: YES)
```

First successful connection was made using `mariadb` command.
Second one, failed connection is from PHP. It seems so that PHP is taking my domain, resolving it, and trying to connection with encryption(?).

Comment: Is your database set to require SSL/TLS? Check out [`mysqli->ssl_set()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.ssl-set.php) or the `MYSQLI_CLIENT_SSL` flag

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Either the server requires a secure connection (setting `require_secure_transport=1`) or the user `test` was created with a required TLS option: REQUIRE SSL, REQUIRE X509 (or unlikely SUBJECT OR ISSUER)

The mariadb command line client tries to connect by default with TLS

```
$> mariadb -uroot -e "SHOW STATUS LIKE 'ssl_cipher'"
+---------------+-----------------------------+
| Variable_name | Value                       |
+---------------+-----------------------------+
| Ssl_cipher    | ECDHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384 |
+---------------+-----------------------------+
```

Since your PHP script doesn't use TLS/SSL at all a secure connection can't be established.

Comment: Or server setting [require_secure_transport=1](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/server-system-variables/#require_secure_transport).